# What are the benefits of Persistence Ignorance?

Tags: domain-driven-design, persistence-ignorance

I am a newbie in the DDD+TDD World. But I have been in programming for almost 9 years.

Can someone please explain me the benefits of persistance ignornace ? Typical nHibernate application just pushes the dependency between class and database to mapping files.

If I change Class files or Database, I have to change the mapping files. So isn't it just pushing the dependency by adding one more abstraction layer? In my opinion so far I don't think it's anything revolutionary. But I am not sure if I am missing something.

Finally How can I test the mapping files ? There are chances bugs will appear from mapping files, how can I test them?

Comment: I added a section about testing to my answer.

Comment: I fell in love with the Repository pattern after listening to [Architecture: The Lost Years](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years).  Every serious app should employ the Repository pattern.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Let me explain this with an example. Lets assume your are implementing an application using a classical SQL approach. You open recordsets, change data and commit it.

Pseudo code:

```cs
trx = connection.CreateTransaction();
query = connection.CreateQuery("Select * from Employee where id = empid");
resultset = query.Run();
resultset.SetValue("Address_Street", "Bahnhofstrasse");
resultset.SetValue("Address_City", "Zürich");
trx.Commit();
```

With NHibernate it would look something like this:

```cs
emp = session.Get<Employee>(empid);

// persistence ignorant 'logic'
emp.Address.Street = "Bahnhofstrasse";
emp.Address.City = "Zürich";

session.Commit();
```

**Persistence Ignorance means that the business logic itself doesn't know about persistence.** Or in other words, persistence is separated from logic. This makes it much more reusable.

Move 'logic' to a reusable method:

```cs
void MoveToZuerichBahnhofstrasse(Employee emp)
{
  // doesn't have anything to do with persistence
  emp.Address.Street = "Bahnhofstrasse";
  emp.Address.City = "Zürich";
}
```

Try to write such a method using resultsets and you know what persistence ignorance is.

If your are not convinced, see how simple a unit test would be, because there aren't any dependencies to persistence related stuff:

```cs
Employee emp = new Employee();
MovingService.MoveToZuerichBahnhofstreasse(emp);
Assert.AreEqual("Bahnhofstrasse", emp.Address.Street);
Assert.AreEqual("Zürich", emp.Address.City);
```

---

DDD is something different. There you build up your domain model first (class model) and create the database design according to it. With NH this is very simple, because - thanks to persistence ignorance - you can write and unit test the model and logic before having a (definitive) database model.

---

Testing: We are testing mappings by creating an instance of the entity, storing it to the database, getting it back and compare it. This is done automatically with lots of reflection. But you don't need to go so far. most of the typical errors show up when trying to store an entity.

You could do the same with queries. Complex queries deserve a test. It's most interesting if the query gets compiled at all. You don't even need any data for this.

For database integration tests, we are using [Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). This is pretty fast. NH produces the in-memory database on the fly using SchemaExport (before each test).

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your great reply.

Comment: is there some persistence-ignorance book or resource to learn?

Answer (score 7):

I've always thought in term of the domain and while I've used stored procedures, ADO.NET in the past, it's only when I finally moved to NHibernate that I was satisfied with my persistence mechanism.

Domain Driven Design (DDD) puts the emphasis squarely on the domain model. This means that the main focus is creating a conceptual model that forms a common language for both the users and programmers. Users are almost NEVER interested in how you are persisting their information. NHibernate helps you achieve this mindset by making persistance a concern that's secondary to capturing business rules and understanding what the user really wants from the system.

[Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) reduces the impact that changes to your domain model have on the underlying mapping files. It also has [auto mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/AutoMapping). While you can never totally ignore persistence for your system, NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate allows you to focus on the domain model. If you're not focusing on using a rich Domain model, there's little benefit to NHibernate.

As regards to testing your mappings, you'd be writing tests (or you SHOULD be) no matter what method you use to implement persistence. This isn't extra work that appears just because you are using NHibernate. Just think of testing your mappings as testing that your persistence works correctly.

Again for this [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) is invaluable. It's got a [Persistence Specification Testing](http://fluentnhibernate.wikia.com/wiki/Persistence_specification_testing) that's really simple to use for most cases.

Comment: Damn you... You beat me for sure. :D

Comment: How can I test mapping files while using DI ? A mock can never gurantee the actual mapping between code and database ? The only option for me is to use actual persistance in tests without mapping?

Comment: FluentNHibernate is not an official part of NHibernate. They even refuse to make it a contribution. NHibernate will likely have its own programmatic mapping configuration in the next major version (3.0).

Comment: +1 for FNH Automapping mention.  IME, it's the fastest and easiest way to get a domain model mapped.

Comment: @Stefan - FNH may not be part of NH, but it reduces a lot of the pain points.  Was unaware they refused to make it a contribution, however.  That's very unfortunate - would be better for everyone if they were more tightly integrated.

Comment: @Tom: It had been some time ago, but the FNH and NH teams weren't able to work together for what ever reason I can't say. It is probably not too bad, independent projects have more freedom. In NH 3.2, there is this new "mapping by code" feature, which is integrated.

Comment: @Stefan - I was just looking at the NH "mapping by code" last week, but as far as I can tell, there's still no equivalent to FNH Automapping, which is a key feature for me.

Answer (score 2):

PI isn't about using NHibernate. PI stands for ignoring how data will be stored developing domain model. And yes, it is pushing dependency by adding one more abstraction layer. DDD isn't revolutionary - it's more like an idea, an approach how to code using already familiar patterns (most of them are). I.e. - factory pattern or module pattern isn't new too, yet quite important part of DDD.

I started to use NHibernate quite recently too, so - can't provide much details about it. But i got one tip that could be useful for You - try [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org) if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Thanks Arnis, I am not saying PI=nHibernate. I am just using it as an example. Fluent Nhibernate is good, I will check it out. But the question is, are there any real benefits of using nHibernate then specially if I am committed to SQL Server as a database?

Comment: I like that NHibernate provides quite clean way to provide persistence (at least - so far). But most of all, i like that it maps data (almost) directly to my POCO's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCO). I believe it fits DDD best.