# Remove coupling between Data Access layer and UI layer

Tags: c#, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I want to design a n-tier architecture for a Windows application. I want to remove coupling between UI layer and data access layer. In the other words, I want the UI layer to depend to the business logic layer only.

Example I have:

```cs
public Class Person
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

in the data access layer, I create new Person in UI layer but I won't call the data access layer. What is the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [MVC - Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern combined with the [DAO - Data Acess Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) design pattern.

The MVC will decouple your UI (user-interface) from the business logic and model (data) and inside the model, you can make use of your data access, using an interface provided by the DAO pattern.

Answer (score 0):

For developing Windows applications and decouple the UI from data access layer it is better to use MVVM pattern see explanation [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

MVVM it allows to decouple the UI from Model, but in order to decouple the Data Access logic from Business logic you need to split your model and I recommend to use Domain Driven Design (DDD)you can read about it [here](https://dddcommunity.org/learning-ddd/what_is_ddd/)

and use the ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

And you should follow the [Persistence Ignorance Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974735/what-exactly-is-persistence-ignorance)

For your example could be following:
in Domain Business logic layer you will have

```
    //Domain Business layer logic
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

interface IPersonRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetAll();

    void Update(Person person);
}
```

in Application layer

```
    //Application logic
class PersonViewModel
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;

    public PersonViewModel(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<Person>(_personRepository.GetAll()); }
    }
}
```

and in the Data Access you will have the implementation of IPersonRepository

```
    //Data Access layer Persistance logic
class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        // ORM Implementation here

        return new List<Person>();
    }

    public void Update(Person person)
    {
      // Update logic here
    }
}
```

Application Layer and Data Access layer should depend on Domain layer and Data Access logic doesn't know nothing about the Application layer