# In Jersey, how do you deal with @POST parameters of a deeply nested, complex object?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-1.0

I'm using Jersey 1.x here and I have a `@POST` method that requires sending over a deeply nested, complex object.  I'm not sure of all my options, but it seems like a lot are [described in this documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.8/user-guide.html#d4e253):

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and
>      java.util.UUID.fromString(String)); or
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

Ideally, I wish that I could define a method like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("complexObject")
public void complexObject(@FormParam("complexObject") ComplexObject complexObject) throws Exception {
```

But I guess I can only do that if my object satisfies the requirements above (which in my case, it does not).  To me it seems that I have a choice.

#### Option 1: Implement `fromString`

Implement item #3 above.

#### Option 2: Pass in the `complexObject` in pieces

Break up the `complexObject` into pieces so the parameters become this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("complexObject")
public void complexObject(@FormParam("piece1") LessComplexPiece lessComplexPiece1, 
@FormParam("piece2") LessComplexPiece lessComplexPiece2, 
@FormParam("piece3") LessComplexPiece lessComplexPiece3) throws Exception {
```

This may not be enough if `LessComplexPiece` does not satisfy the requirements above.  I'm wondering what the best option is here.  What do people usually do in this situation?  Here are the pros and cons I can think of:

## Cons of Implement `fromString`

- Have to maintain a custom deserializer.  Every time the class is modified, this deserializer may break.  There's more risk for bugs in general.
- It will probably be impossible to generate documentation that describes the pieces of the complex object.  I'll have to write that by hand.
- For each piece of the complex object, I'll have to write my own casting and validation logic.
- I'm not sure what the post data would look like.  But, this may make it very difficult for someone to call the API from a web page form.  If the resource accepted primitives, it would be easy. EG: `complexObject=seralizedString` vs `firstName=John` and `lastName=Smith`
- You may not be able to modify the class for various reasons (thankfully, this is not a limitation for me)

## Pros of Implementing `fromString`

- This could avoid a method with a ton of parameters.  This will make the API less intimidating to use.
- This argument is at the level of abstraction I want to work at in the body of my method:
- I won't have to combine the pieces together by hand (well technically I will, it'll just have to be in the deserializer method)
- The deserializer can be a library that automates the process (XStream, gensen, etc.) and save me a lot of time.  This can mitigate the bug risk.
- You may run into "namespace" clashes if you flatten the object to send over pieces.  For example, imagine sending over an `Employee`.  If he has a `Boss`, you now have to provide a `EmployeeFirstName` and a `BossFirstName`.  If you were just deserializing an object, you could nest the data appropriately and not have to include context in your parameter names.

So which option should I choose?  Is there a 3rd option I'm not aware of?

Comment: Have you considered using JSON or XML binding instead of URL-encoded string to pass your object in so you can rely on JAXB?

Comment: @TheArchitect I've looked into it but I'm having trouble getting it working.  But even if I do, it just makes the server side logic easier.  I think the client side issues I bring up are valid with that approach.

Comment: The client may leverage JAXB as well to marshall the input param. If you're using the Jersey client it's completely transparent. If not, you can still invoke the JAXB Marshaller on your object before sending. If you use XML binding, XSD is a great specification and documentation to share with the client.

Comment: @TheArchitect The client will be lots of languages like javascript and php, not just java.  That's a good point re: XSD though.  I planned on serializing to JSON but maybe I should use XML for that reason.

Comment: Right many languages have code-generators to compile an XSD into model classes and marshallers

Comment: @TheArchitect I went with JAXB and am using enunciate to document it.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this question is old but in case anybody has this problem there is new better solution since JAX-RS 2.0. Solution is @BeanParam. Due to documentation:

> The annotation that may be used to inject custom JAX-RS "parameter aggregator" value object into a resource class field, property or resource method parameter.
>   The JAX-RS runtime will instantiate the object and inject all it's fields and properties annotated with either one of the @XxxParam annotation (@PathParam, @FormParam ...) or the @Context annotation. For the POJO classes same instantiation and injection rules apply as in case of instantiation and injection of request-scoped root resource classes.

If you are looking for extended explanation on how this works please look at article I've found:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-jax-rs-20-%E2%80%93-beanparam

Answer (score 1):

For complex object models, you may want to consider using JSON or XML binding instead of URL-encoded string to pass your objects to your resource call so you can rely on JAXB framework?
The Jersey Client library is compatible with JAXB and can handle all the marshaling transparently for you if you annotate your classes @XmlElementRoot.

For documentation, XSDs are a good starting point if you choose the XML binding. 
Other REST documentation tools like enunciate can take the automatic generation to the next level.

Answer (score 0):

What about special handler which transforms object to e.g. json - kryo if you would prefer performance? You got [couple options](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html)

Look also at [persistence ignorance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905498/what-are-the-benefits-of-persistence-ignorance).