# Is it acceptable to use UnitOfWork from inside an entity

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I've been developing an `ASP.NET MVC4` project from scratch by myself using separate project for my data access layer. There I am using `Entity Framework 5` with `Code First` workflow and I've implemented I think a very standard `Repository pattern` plus `Uint Of Work` to separate the data layer from the business logic.

Everything was working as expected and I have already a lot of business logic, but I don't have too much experience (about 9 months total) and now a very experienced developer is joining to the project and suddenly I started to get this error:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different  ObjectContext objects.

The structure of my project is this -

[image: Solution screenshot]

Just a part from my `UnitOfWork` class :

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext ();

    private MenuRepository мenuRepository;
    public MenuRepository MenuRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.мenuRepository == null)
                this.мenuRepository = new MenuRepository(context);
            return мenuRepository;
        }
    }

    //register other repositories...
}
```

And the my repositories have a standard look:

```
 public class MenuRepository : GenericRepository<Menu>, IMenuRepository
 {
     public MenuRepository(MyDbContext context) : base(context) { }
 }
```

I know that this is not enough to tell if the implementation is good enough or not but it was working for a few months without noticing any problems. Today I was implementing a logic for editing a menu with submenus :

```
Menu menu = unitOfWork.MenuRepository.GetById(model.MenuID);
    long menuItemId = menu.MenuItems[0].MenuItemID;
    if (menu != null)
    {
      menu.Name = model.MenuName;
      MenuItem menuItem = unitOfWork.MenuItemRepository.GetById(menuItemId);
      menuItem.Name = "Test";

      unitOfWork.MenuRepository.Update(menu);

      return View(model);
    }
```

This is all happening in my controller where I have this :

```
private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

So when I tried to execute this code I got the error from above for the `..attached to different ObjectContext objects.`.

The only change that I've noticed from before the code started to crash was this added from the other guy directly into the `Menu` entity :

```
//private DAL.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new DAL.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork();
    public Menu()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    //private int menuId;
    //public int MenuID {
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return menuId;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        menuId = value;
    //        if (MenuItems.Count == 0)
    //        {
    //            MenuItems = unitOfWork.MenuItemRepository.GetBy(x => x.MenuID == menuId).ToList();
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
```

After I commented all the stuff above and returned it to `public int MenuID { get; set; }` without the additional logic, dropping the database and recreating it I was able to continue to use my `Update` logic from the controller without the error for the different object contexts.

So my question is - is using `UnitOfWork` directly from the entity acceptable at all. I've implemented the `Data Access Layer` but I've used a lot of information from different articles and I can't say that I fully understand the reason behind everything. However it seems to me that using it this way not only causes the code to crash but also is against the whole idea for using `Repositories` and `UnitOfWork` to manage your data. On the other hand the guy that has added this code has more than 10 years of programming experience so I can't just tell him he must change his code. So is it in fact OK to use `unitOfWork` from inside the entity itself as in the example above and if it's actually is, then how can I resolve the error with the different object contexts being used?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not ok for a domain object to use the unit of work. The domain model should be persistence ignorrant. That post contains information on why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905498/what-are-the-benefits-of-persistence-ignorance. plus that article from msdn resume it well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion (which isn't necessarily valid, I have little ASP experience), in this case, the entity definitely shouldn't be using the UnitOfWork, or even be aware of it.

If you already have configured `Menu` entities which entity framework is managing, and you have several existing repositories set up to further abstract & manage your database interactions, it doesn't make sense to pollute your model.

I'm assuming the error is appearing because the new `UnitOfWork` the other developer has defined in the model is a new context, and the `Menu` entity has already been obtained from another context (your `MenuRepository`), which you've already figured out.

It seems like the other developer is attempting to load the child `MenuItems` if there aren't any present in the `Menu` entity, when setting the MenuID. It's not entirely clear to me what's going on there, it seems as if they're expecting the item to have its ID changed, and then wanting to obtain the `MenuItems` belonging to `Menu` with the new ID (I'm not sure why you'd want to change the ID).

The `MenuItem` loading should be possible at the time the entity is retrieved, or afterward depending on how the entities are mapped/configured, using `Lazy`, `Eager`, or `Explicit` loading.

It's certainly worth talking to the other developer and finding out what they're trying to achieve, don't be worried about the amount of experience someone has (or says they have), many of these concepts may be new to them as well, or they may have spent all that time reinforcing bad habits, good programmers should always be willing to have a discussion about various approaches.

Some extra info on loading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @Christ It's pretty unclear for me too. The navigation properties are set and the lazy loading is working as it's described it should be, so I really don't know what one may achieve by populating the property like this, but as I said I'm far from being an expert I hope to turn it to a win-win situation where I either will learn something new about how to use this pattern or be able to defend the opinion which as it seems, you share, that `UOW` was not meant to be used this way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Leron I'm by no means an expert either =D It seems like the other developer is a `Menu` entity to potentially be re-assigned to represent a different `Menu` entity, and wants to ensure that if that happens, the correct children are loaded. With your design (repository and uow patterns), that shouldn't need to be done. Definitely worth a discussion. Hopefully a few more answers will chip in some opinions.